# Editable Label/Div losing focus on click

Tags: gwt

I have an editable GWT Label which shows a strange behavior. That is if I click the text “Add note…” the cursor does not appear until I click a second time. But if I click on the label outside the text the cursor appears on first click. How do I solve that? My guess is that replacing the text also removes the cursor when the cursor is in the text. So how can I get the cursor back on first click?

```
public class EditableLabel extends Label implements FocusHandler {

    public EditableLabel() {
        super();
        getElement().setAttribute("contenteditable", "true");
        getElement().setAttribute("tabindex", "1");
        this.sinkEvents(Event.ONBLUR);
        this.sinkEvents(Event.ONFOCUS);
        addHandler(this, FocusEvent.getType());
        setText("Add note...");
    }

    @Override
    public void onFocus(FocusEvent event) {
        setText("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem depends on the browser. On FF it works fine for me.

I assume you want to write something, if so try to change `Label` for `TextBox`, it should work.

Comment: You are right it works in FF, but not in Chrome. And I would really prefer the Label if that is possible.